# Freeze during [update-initramfs -u]: 'unable to enumerate USB device'

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia, initramfs

While following the Nvidia installation documentation https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-nouveau-ubuntu I had to regenerate the kernel initramfs.

I ran the command while being in runlevel 3 (not running startx yet in order to finish installing nvidia/cuda).

Although I am not completely sure I understand what is happening, my system  (debian 9, stretch, the hardware being almost new) hangs at this screen for almost an hour now.

EDIT: I hit enter, and got the regular prompt back.
I don't know what did or did not happen.

Is there perhaps a way to know if the command had the desired effect(s)?

[image]